# How to detect finger on back camera of iPhone?

Tags: ios, avcapturesession

I want to start and stop capture session by covering camera by finger and removing it respectively. Is there any kind of sensor to detect it?

Comment: There are no touch sensors on the camera.  I'd suggest rethinking your approach.  Perhaps what CocoaChris said.  Or... why not just a button on the screen?

Comment: dint get u on later part..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a way to do so. I have converted the RGB to HSV and then i just restricted to hue boundary, so whenever i get value beyond this boundary session stops.

Comment: What hue values, specifically, indicate a finger is on the camera?

Comment: I have done it long back so I have forgotten it. But you can do hit and trial to observe the values... And then you can create your filter and sampling of the data..

Answer (score 0):

No, but you can grab a still and filter out the ratio of black pixels vs light. Which probably won't help you if it's dark :-)

Comment: Flash is also on. So I don't think so there will be dark. but I want to react on finger touch only.